# WPF - checkbox template

Tags: wpf, templates, checkbox, styles

I need to create a 2 option button, look like this:

[image]

When the left side selected it's turned to green and the right side turned to gray and vice versa.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: First of all you need a CustomControl instead of CheckBox. You must write your own custom control template and in template use two RadioButtons(write a control template for the radio button as well to override the default style). Manipulate IsChecked property of RadioButton to show this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

the question is too broad

you should override the [default style of CheckBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319.aspx) create 2 CheckBoxs and put them in a `GroupBox`, this should cover your requirement since checking one will mutually exclude the other

p.s
if you are having problems with creating your own style then you should post your XAML and try explaining what you are having difficulty with..